# Chart is being resized not proportionally

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I use Chart on Windows Forms. And I've noticed, chart is being resized not proportionally. Why is it so and how can I change it. For better understanding look at follow pictures (Chart's *width x height* in top left angle)

[image]
[image]

Comment: What kind of Chart is that supposed to be? The Data.chart?? Neither looks like it not should that resize only proportionally. Looks like a Form, yes? You need to restrict the resize behaviour yourself, as doing so would be usually a nightmare for the user. Use the Resize event!

Comment: @TaW, yes, I got it and have already done it.

Comment: So you have solved the problem?

Comment: @TaW, Yes, I did it simple. Look at the pictures above. Circle is more pretty when resolution is 490x455. I handle a resize event and set `width = height + 35`

Comment: Well, if you are happy, then fine.. But the reason is probably that you have non-square pixels and a fixed correction of '+35' is not good for other sizes even on you monitor. You should do a few test on other monitors.. On mine the 1st image looks nice and round, the other is wide..

Comment: @TaW, I've not even thought about that. It's really interesting. Thanks a lot!